# Akka streams reduce to smaller stream

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, reactive-streams

I have an ordered stream of data

```
A A A B B C C C C ... (very long)
```

And I want to transform it to a stream of aggregates in the form (item, count):

```
(A, 3) (B, 2) (C, 4)
```

What operators could I use in Akka Streams for this?

```
Source.fromPublisher(publisher)
    .aggregateSomehow()  // ?
    .runWith(sink)
```

I've looked into [.groupBy](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0/scala/stream-cookbook.html#Implementing_reduce-by-key) but it requires that I know the number of categories in advance which I don't. Also I believe it will keep all groups in memory which I'd like to avoid. I should be able to discard (A, 3) after it has been processed and free up resources it consumes.

**Edit**: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45436102) ask for similar functionality but using SubFlows. However using SubFlows doesn't seem to be required because I have a solution using the `statefulMapConcat` combinator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I group items of sorted stream with SubFlows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45436102/how-do-i-group-items-of-sorted-stream-with-subflows)

Comment: @chunjef Thanks for the pointer! It is certainly related though not sure if a duplicate. It seems SubFlows are not necessarily required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the [statefulMapConcat](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/FlowOps.html#statefulMapConcat-scala.Function0-) combinator:

```
Source(List("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", ""))
      .statefulMapConcat({ () =>
        var lastChar = ""
        var count = 0

        char => if(lastChar == char) {
            count += 1
            List.empty
          } else {
            val charCount = (lastChar, count)
            lastChar = char
            count = 1
            List(charCount)
          }
      })
    .runForeach(println)
```

However that required appending an element to the input stream to mark the end.

Output:

```
(,0)
(A,2)
(B,3)
(C,2)
```

Thanks to @chunjef for the suggestion in comments